# Remove Folders in command line With Wild Cards

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a Windows 2003 Server and need to remove all folder through command line that start with people.

I tried rmdir people* and rd people* but those command don't seem to accept wildcards

Is there any simple command to do this without use for looks to find all folder and delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `FOR` construct with `/d` to limit to directories;

```
for /d %n in (c:\blah\people*) do @echo "%n"
```

replacing `@echo` with `rd` once you've tested.